# secondsFromGMT returns different values on device and simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, timezone, nsdate

I am working on a time app which display time of different time zones. For this i am using a standard time `haDate` (UTC tz).

For `displayDate` i am using system time zone api. Time Zone is `America/Santiago` (UTC-3:00).

```
NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:_timeZone];
_displayDate=[_haDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:tz.secondsFromGMT];
```

"haDate" code -

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.timeZone=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSString *utcTimeCurrent=[dict objectForKey:@"utctime"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
_haDate=[formatter dateFromString:utcTimeCurrent];
```

The issue is when i run this code on simulator `tz.secondsFromGMT` returns `-10800` but on device it returns `-14400`, which is 1 hour less.

Device and Simulator using same timeZone `Asia/Kolkata` (UTC+5:30). I know `America/Santiago` uses DST but why it is giving me different seconds even both (simulator and device) are on same timeZone.

What is wrong and how can i fix it?

***NOTE***

To fix DST issue i am using this code. But it always go to the else part on both devices. **(BTW below code is not required because `tz.secondsFromGMT` always return seconds after DST adjustments.)**

```
NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:_timeZone];
if (tz.isDaylightSavingTime)
{
    _displayDate=[_haDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:tz.secondsFromGMT+tz.daylightSavingTimeOffset];
}
else
{
    _displayDate=[_haDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:tz.secondsFromGMT];
}
```

When i log the tz -

On Simulator

`tz America/Santiago (GMT-3) offset -10800`

On Device

`tz America/Santiago (GMT-4) offset -14400`

So it is not using DST.

***NOTE 2***

This problem only occurs in iPad 2. Other devices working fine.

***NOTE 3***

My iPad 2 using iOS 8.4 . Both time zones (Chile Standard Time -`America/Santiago` and Easter Island Standard Time - `Pacific/Easter`) are giving me wrong seconds

Comment: Can you check whether the value of _timeZone is the same for all you setups?

Comment: @JoeSmith yes, it is .

Comment: What's the value of _timeZone? Where does it come from?

Comment: @JoeSmith _timeZone is a string and value is `America/Santiago`. It stored in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chile changed the TZ at the beginning of 2015. Probably your iPad 2 has an iOS Version using an outdated time zone database. Update it.

> Time in Chile is divided into two time zones. Continental Chile uses the time offset UTC−03:00. Additionally, Easter Island uses the time offset UTC−05:00.[1]
>
> Until 2015, Continental Chile used the time offset UTC−04:00 and Easter Island used UTC−06:00 for standard time, with daylight saving time roughly between October and March every year. However, in January 2015 it was announced that all the country will keep the time offset used during daylight saving time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Chile

Comment: My ipad has ios 8.4. And yes one thing more both time zones (Continental Chile and Easter Island ) are giving me wrong seconds. Question updated.

Comment: Hmmm, iOS 8 released in Sep 2014, 8.4 in Mid 2015. Maybe Apple didn't want to change the TZ on older devices for some reasons? What happens if you try another town in the same TZ, but outside Chile?

Comment: i have an iPhone 4S (late 2011) and the time is correct on 4S. It having issue on iPad 2 only.

Comment: Really weird. File a bug? Did you read about the GMT bug? Are you connected to other calendars on the iPad? (Google, MS)

Comment: Yes i filed a bug. there is no other calendar service i am using.